# How to add onClick event to button using properties section in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know how to add onClick event to button using properties section in Android Studio.

When I open onClick section, there is not any item only "none".

But I create hello word method `public void showToast()`.

I don't want to write some listener, etc. I want use properties section.

Comment: `android:onClick = yourMethodName` should do it.

Comment: It is better to set a click listener explicitly for each view. So even if you "don't want to write some listener" - in the long run it will be better if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From properties in front of `onClick` add a method name say "showToast"

It will add the following line in that view in your `xml`

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout elements -->
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="showToast" //**THIS LINE**
/> 
<!-- even more layout elements -->
```

Then in your java class (Activity) add a method with the same name

```
   public void showToast(View v) {
    // does something
    }
```

Comment: android studio have shortcut for it?